# jsdoc hide Inherited method (in generated doc)

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm using jsdoc to generate online doc for my javascript project.

It works fine except one problem I'm having right now.

Say I have a base class with lots of get/set functions.

```
/**
 * cc.BaseClass
 * @class
 * @extends cc.Class
 */
cc.BaseClass = cc.Class.extend(/** @lends cc.BaseClass# */{
    /** 
     * @param {number} a
     */
    setA:function(a){},
    /** 
     * @return {number}
     */
    getA:function(){},
    // ...... 20+ more
});
```

Then I have a child class which extends the base class.

```
/**
 * cc.ChildClass
 * @class
 * @extends cc.BaseClass
 */
cc.ChildClass = cc.BaseClass.extend(/** @lends cc.ChildClass# */{
    /** 
     * @param {number} xxx
     */
    myFunction:function(xxx){}
});
```

My problem is the generated online DOC for the cc.ChildClass contains the "myFunction:function" along with the 20+ get/set functions inherited from the cc.BaseClass.

I know there is nothing wrong about this but I want to know if there is a way to hide all the 20+ get/set functions inherited from the cc.BaseClass in the doc for cc.ChildClass.

Think if I have cc.ChildClassA cc.ChildClassB cc.ChildClassC ... then I don't want to see each of their doc contains the 20+ get/set functions inherited from the cc.BaseClass.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You shoudn't adapt your code / classes for satisfying this. This should be the responsiblity of the template. This one does the trick very well: https://github.com/steveush/foodoc - demo: https://cancerberosgx.github.io/jsdoc-templates-demo/demo/foodoc/Apple.html  . Another one that supports it is ibm's amddcl. In the following look for https://cancerberosgx.github.io/jsdoc-templates-demo/demo/amddcl/Apple.html#

Some other templates dont show inherithed at all and dont allwo the user to toccle - which I also dont want. I think foodoc allows both the user and the compiler-person to configure it nicely.

BTW I'm trying to collect well known jsdoc templates demos here https://cancerberosgx.github.io/jsdoc-templates-demo/demo/ - for each there are installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I could come up with is to remove @extend. I added a link to the extended class manually to the description. This works for me in this instance because I do not need @extends for anything else.